docker container is running in os not accessible in browser
my simple docker container is running(i have run  docker run -d -p 8080:80 -d nginx:stable-alpine3.20-perl)
root@manual:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                     NAMES
95d7a0079959   nginx:stable-alpine3.20-perl   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   38 minutes ago   Up 38 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, [::]:8080->80/tcp   my_nginx

the port mapping to ip is fine and im getting html response when i do
http://localhost:8080/
my firewall is not enabled
I'm able to access the link inside container and port 80 is also exposed in there
what could be the problem?
nginx is not opening in web browser

"the port mapping to ip is fine and im getting html response" ... I don't understand why you think there's a problem. What response did you receive and what response did you expect to receive?

Are you running your container on WSL?
If yes, please ensure its version 2. Also, your network might be messed up, you could try to use docker-compose file with bridge network that will handle it for you.

Im running docker on private cloud provided by hostinger. Ive tried docker compose for my whole application the issue was almost similar.so wanted to troubleshoot by running single simple image. Docker network inspect reveals port binding an ip tobe fine.

In this case, my only guess is a firewall setting.
You stated that it's disabled but it also could be external security group or other entity that cloud provider use for this purpose
